# Want to make the arrow with border responsive

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive-design

How do I make this arrow box responsive?

Here is my code for now:

```
<div class="arrow-box"></div>

.arrow-box {
    border-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #13aac5;
    border-bottom: 0;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 240px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -63px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 62px 501px 0 501px;
        border-color: #13aac5 transparent transparent transparent;
        content: '';
    }
    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 62px 500px 0 500px;
        border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
        content: '';
        bottom: -62px;
    }

}
```

you can have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinnlee/s2op4em1/5/)

It's work as expected on desktop, but it's not responsive, can anyone help me to make it responsive?

Comment: You're using hard-coded pixel-based values for your widths. Simply replace these with percentage-based values.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have put the percent values on border-width of the arrow in the media query, but it not worked.

Comment: I would recommend to use embedded SVG image for an arrow instead of trying to construct it using CSS

Comment: @Flying I have tried it with a background image but because I have to put some paragraph and a list of item in it, and the background image doesn't responsive correctly, so I have to handle it with css.

Comment: @vinnlee Actually it is possible to apply background image not for a whole element but just for `::after` that represents your arrow below element. It will make your main element independent from image but will allow you to create required arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `vw` unit which is percentage of viewport width.
[Read more](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

```css
.arrow-box {
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #13aac5;
  border-bottom: 0;
  width: 96vw;
  height: 240px;
  margin:auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}

.arrow-box:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -63px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 62px 48vw 0;
  border-color: #13aac5 transparent transparent transparent;
  content: '';
}

.arrow-box:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 62px 48vw 0;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  content: '';
  bottom: -62px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-box"></div>
```

**Update**
Using `vw` units with container (see comments in CSS):

```css
.container {
  width: 80vw; /* say we want to have it 80% of our viewport */
}

.arrow-box {
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #13aac5;
  border-bottom: 0;
  width: 76vw; /* it should be little less than .container because of shadow
                * or you may set it more precizely with calc(80vw - 42px)  */
  height: 240px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 21px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}

.arrow-box:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -63px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 62px 38vw 0; /* 50% of .arrow-box width */
  border-color: #13aac5 transparent transparent transparent;
  content: '';
}

.arrow-box:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 62px 38vw 0;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
  content: '';
  bottom: -62px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please answer me a more little question :). If I put it in a container with a width of 1000px then how do I calculate vw for it?

Comment: @vinnlee, you have to set the "container" width using `vw` units as well and update the `arrow-box` params accordingly. See the update in my answer.